# How can I expand my workplace in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCkl8.png)

I want to move this line to the right because I want more space to code, how can I do it?

Comment: you shouldn't, because dartfmt will still wrap your code at 80 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by  disabling/unchecking `Show hard wrap guide(configured in code style options)` from settings in Android studio

`File-->Settings-->Editor-->General-->Appearance-->Disable Show hard wrap guide(configured in code style options)`Apply and OK

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't disable this option, but with your help I saw the "configured in code style options" tip on this option and then I went to Editor --> Code Style --> Dart --> Wrapping and Braces and changed the 'Hard wrap at' to '120', in my case it was enough to move the line and make more space to write my code. If other Android Studio users find this question, I suggest to change this propriety on the language you are using (in my case it was Dart).
Thank you very very much, this problem was very annoying!

Comment: You can add that as answer here